# Java method to multiply an ArrayList of decimal values by an array of doubles to get an array of ints?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Help! I have this school assignment that wants me to write a method to find the area of rectangles (an array of ints) by multiplying width (an ArrayList) by length (an array of doubles). I'm very very new to coding; I've tried for over five hours to get this working, but I keep doing things wrong and I simply can't get it right. This is the code for the method that I've written:

```
public void calcRectangleArea(int index, ArrayList width, double[] length, int[] area) 
{ 
    double temp = length[index]; 
    for(index = 0; index < length.length; index++) 
    { 
        for(index = 0; index < width.size(); index++) 
        { 
            Object widthObj = (int)width.get(index); 
            area[index] = temp * widthObj; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The full starter code we were given is here, if you need more context (it's commented): http://pastie.org/pastes/916496

Thank you so much for any help you can give me in writing this method. I've been working for hours and I just can't get it...

Comment: As a hint, your `length` Array must have the same number of elements in it as the `width` ArrayList.  Furthermore, the following is probably valid based on the assignment: `area[index] = length[index] * width.get(index);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the array and size of the arraylist should be same , And you have to change the method logic a bit, Have a look at the below code snippet

```
public static int[] calcRectangleArea(List<Double> width, double[] length) 
    { 
        int[] area=new int[length.length];
        for(int index = 0; index < length.length; index++) 
        { 
            area[index] = (int) (length[index]*width.get(index));
        }
        return area; 
    }
```

Call this method passing width arraylist and length array. It will return area array of ints

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need two loops here.  Assuming that width[1] correlates to length[1] you can just loop through both collections at the same time in the same loop.

This should work (i haven't written a line of java in ~2 years so it may not be 100%)

```
public void calcRectangleArea(int index, ArrayList width, double[] length, int[] area) 
{ 
    //assuming length.length == width.size
    for(index = 0; index < length.length; index++) 
    { 
       int anArea = (int)(width.get(index) * length[index]); 
       area[index]=anArea;

    } 
}
```

again the code above assumes the size of the collections are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to assign temporary variables:

```
double temp = length[index];
```

...

```
Object widthObj = (int)width.get(index);
```

Since you will only reference them once. Reference them directly instead:

```
area[index] = length[index] * (int)width.get(index);
```

Secondly, your for loops are unneeded, and they are declared wrong. You're trying to increment the index (and twice nonetheless) that was passed to the function which will cause problems. If you were to use nested for loops, you would declare a new iterator variable for each of them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < somethingElse; j++) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

However in this case you don't even need them.

In addition, you should not have created an Object when you wanted to cast an int:

```
Object widthObj = (int)width.get(index);
```

should have been

```
int width = (int)width.get(index);
```

However again, this line is unnecessary, and you shouldn't be casting to int this early.

Ultimately, all you need to do is the one line:

```
area[index] = (int)(length[index] * width.get(index));
```